# Is it necessary to mention age on nikkah papers?

Tags: nikah

If the girl is 4 years older than the boy. And they are getting married next month. But mentioning their age on the nikkah papers will make alot of people question them. Specially people who will be the witness. Is it important to write age on nikkah papers for both? Or if the age written is incorrect will the nikkah b valid?
Ps. The parents of both the party knows the age difference.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you mean by nikah papers: As for a 'aqd an-Nikah what must or should be inside is: the agreement of the bride and her guardian the names of the bride her guardian and the fiancé and the conditions each of them may have and maybe also the amount of mahr/sadaq. Age or date of birth may play a role in civil marriage papers,

Answer (score 2):

Islamically there's not need for a certificate or a piece of paper. The conditions for Nikah in Islam are as follows:

> 1. The groom and bride or their representatives should be present in the Nikah
> 2. The groom or bride should say that I have taken you in return for this much of Mahr and the other party should say that they accept and agree.
> 3. Two male witnesses or one male and two female witnesses should be present during the khutba of Nikah.
> 4. The witnesses should hear the whole transaction from start to end.

As for mentioning the age, it's not required neither on paper nor in words. I guess mentioning the name of the would-be couples, witnesses and the date on which the marriage takes place are enough for a marriage certificate-- unless the country you are in requires one's age to be on there as well.

Allah (SWT) knows best.